# Ajax call to return PartialView is returning entire Layout page and partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have some links in my `_Layout.cshtml` page, something like:

```
<li><a onclick="aboutPage(); return false;" href="fallback.html">About</a></li>
```

And inside my `Layout` page I have:

```
<div id="mainSection">
   <!-- Render individual pages -->
   @RenderBody()
</div>
```

The `a` tag then calls:

```
function aboutPage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/About/Index',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#mainSection').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Inside my `AboutController` I have

```
public ActionResult Index() {
       return View();
}
```

but have also tried:

```
public PartialViewResult Index() {
       return PartialView();
       //return PartialView("~/Views/About/Index.cshtml");
}
```

But in all cases, the returned data is the entire `_Layout.cshtml` page with the `About` page inside the `mainSection` div. I then get the result you would expect, it is the `About` page, with the entire page again, including navigation and everything, inside the `mainSection` div.

Comment: Are you sure it did not work when you tried `return PartialView();`?

Comment: Yes, I even debugged the aJax call and checked the returned `data` object, it contains 100% of the HTML inside `_Layout` AND `About`

Comment: From the `About` page, I just removed `@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}` and it seems to return just the HTML inside `About` now. But that shouldn't be the case right?

Comment: @x540 Yes, that's exactly how it's supposed to work. If you want the ability to have both a standalone About page and have the contents of the About page shown in the MainContent div of another page, you would need to move the actual content of About.cshtml to another view that does not have the layout attribute. You then reference that new partial view from within About.cshtml as well as from the controller method called by your Ajax call. But why is that needed? The URL of your page won't change (unless you code that client-side) and it might lead to issues with bookmarks and SEO.

Comment: @Speedbird186 yes the primary issue is I don't know how to properly load new pages as a single-page-app with aJax while having all those things still work properly. I cannot find any resources that explain how to do it correctly.

Comment: @x540 ASP.NET MVC by itself probably isn't the framework to build SPAs. You will probably need to combine it with some Javascript framework like Angular or Knockout.js. See http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was under the impression ASP.NET generally supported that sort of thing out of the box